# Redewendung: „in die Luft zu stehen kommen“. Was soll das heißen?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom

Könntet ihr mir vielleicht helfen, diese Redewendung zu entziffern? Erstmal ein Wort über den Zusammenhang, wo ich sie gefunden habe:

Es geht darum, wie der römische Historiker Sallust einige Ereignisse zeitlich verschoben oder umgestaltet hat. Unter anderem verschiebt er ein Treffen der Verschwörer um Catilina, das bei Laeca zu Hause stattfand, auf ein anderes Datum. Außerdem blendet er die sehr berühmte Rede Ciceros gegen Catilina aus seiner Darstellung aus. Der Autor des Artikels behauptet, Sallust habe parteiisch gegen Cicero geschrieben. Also:

> Der grösste Vortheil, den die Verschiebung der Versammlung bei Laeca Sallust brachte, war der, dass die erste catilinarische Rede in die Luft zu stehen kam.
>   ([Eduard Schwartz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Schwartz), *Die Berichte über die catilinarische Verschwörung*. [Hermes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermes_%28Zeitschrift%29) 32 (1897), 554–608; hier Seite 577. [Scan](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_paSkinU_Z2sC) beim Internet Archive.)

Was soll das denn heißen?

Comment: Könntest Du bitte prüfen, ob da 'in die Luft' oder 'in der Luft' steht?

Comment: Habe ich noch nie gehört und habe auch keine Vorstellung, was es heißen sollte. Von wann ist denn der Text?

Comment: Und ist der irgendwann mal hin- und herübersetzt worden? Originalsprache?

Comment: Ich nehme an, in der Orginalsprache (glaube kaum, dass das Deutsch ist; ich habe das noch nie gehört oder gelesen), sollte transportiert warden, dass die Catilina-Rede *im Nirvana landete*, *unter den Tisch fiel* o. ä.

Comment: OK, hab’s gefunden; es ist wirklich _in die Luft_ und ein deutschsprachiger Autor, allerdings vor 120 Jahren. Werde die Details gleich in die Frage einarbeiten.

Comment: Einziger weiterer Beleg, soweit mit Google zu finden: aus einem Buch [_Versuche mit Pflanzen_](https://books.google.de/books?id=U0Q-AAAAcAAJ&lpg=PR61&ots=jWPvsRB-lg&dq=%22in%20die%20luft%20zu%20stehen%22&pg=PR61#v=onepage&q=%22in%20die%20luft%20zu%20stehen%22&f=false) von 1790 (_daß die Wurzel unter das Wasser und die Blätter in die Luft zu stehen kommen_). Außerdem habe ich dieses Crossposting gefunden: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-die-luft-zu-stehen-kam.3144937/

Comment: Jedenfalls ist es keine Redewendung, sondern nur ein sprachlicher Ausdruck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Formulierung ist mir auch neu, aber auf der folgenden Seite wird klar, was hier gemeint sein muss:

> Sallust aber vergrössert den Fehler der ciceronischen Politik ins Ungeheure dadurch, dass er der ersten Rede gegen Catilina nicht nur mit perfider Deutung von Ciceros eigenen Worten die bösesten Folgen zuschreibt, sondern ihr auch die factische Unterlage raubt. Bei ihm spricht nicht der Consul, der einen Tag vorher einem niederträchtigen Attentat entronnen ist, dem sich ein detaillirter Mordbrennerplan enthüllt hat, sondern ein nervöser Mensch, der sich ärgert zugleich und fürchtet wegen der Frechheit Catilinas, der, obgleich angeklagt, munter und unverfroren im Senat erscheint.

Gemeint ist hier also, dass durch die Verfälschungen Sallusts die erste catilinarische Rede in einen falschen Kontext gesetzt und dadurch ihrer Grundlage beraubt wurde - sozusagen in die Luft gebaut erscheint statt auf das solide Fundament bedeutender Ereignisse.

Comment: Wow, toll toll toll. Danke Hans!